# Firebase collection.where not working on real Android device

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, device

My Application uses FireBase, both for authentication and store data.
If i try my app on simulator, or connect device and run in debug mode, firebase collection.where works fine, get data etc.
But if i make an aab/apk, and install it on the same device, i got the error:
Bad state:no element.
Have someone the same error?
Thanks for any help!!!

code is:

```
Future<User> getLoggedInUserData(String userId) async {
    //try {
      FS.QuerySnapshot q = await collection
          .where('uid', isEqualTo: userId)
          .get();
      EasyLoading.showToast(q.docs.isEmpty.toString());
      FS.DocumentSnapshot d = await q.docs.first;
      FS.DocumentSnapshot document = await collection.doc(d.id).get();
      return User.fromSnapshot(document);
    //}catch(e){
    //  EasyLoading.showToast(e.toString());
    //}
  }
```

if i run it on simulator or a connected device, it works fine, when i make an apk, install it to the same device, the QuerySnapshot "q" is empty. Please help!!!

Comment: Did you add your SHA keys to firebase console? Are you building release or debugging APKs?

Comment: i build release APK

Comment: no SHA Keys added

Comment: Try to add sha keys.

Answer (score 0):

Finally...
The key is gradle.
Because some of my used packages needs
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4' in android/build.gradle
(i cannot use the build:gradle:4.1.2)
and build:gradle:3.6.4 doesn't works with gardle distribution 6.7, simply change distribution to 5.6.4 in app/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and it work fine!